TCL read variables with a dynamically increasing number
We create dynamic variables in a foreach loop like this:
set res01_ipsladata [split [exec "show ip sla history"] \n]
set res01_lineindicator 0
foreach line $res01_ipsladata {
    if {[llength $line] >= 1} {
        incr res01_lineindicator
        set res01_hop$res01_lineindicator [lindex $line 3]
        set res01_rtt$res01_lineindicator [lindex $line 5]
    }
}

So basically we have a bunch of variables after this run that look like this:
res01_hop1
res01_hop2
res01_hop3
res01_hop...

So you get the idea. Now i want to output these variables one by one:
for {set a 1} {$a <= $highesthopcount} {incr a} {
    puts "showing variable $res01_hop$a"
}

So basically i expect the loop to get me the output of all variables res01_hop1 to max. but instead i get the error:
can't read "res01_hop": no such variable

So how can i "merge" these tho variables so that they are getting read as a single one?

Use a dict or array instead of trying to create variable names at runtime.

You'r welcome:
set a 1
set res01_hop$a abc
puts "showing variable [set res01_hop$a]"


You are the genious, it works. Thank you so much for this quick solution. I didnt know that if you set a variable that it will show its content if you dont provide data to fill it...

We don't really encourage it; it's usually a sign that one ought to be using an array instead. (Or upvar in some cases.)
